# Is ${\tau(2^n-1)}$ always divides $\phi(2^n-1)$ for every integer $n \geq 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm always interesting for properties  of the following series : $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}$  such that :$\tau(N)$ is the number of divisor of $N$  and $\phi$ is Euler totiont function ,In this question i w'd be interest to know a little bit about the receprocal of each term of the titled series at $N=2^n-1$ for every $n\geq 1$.

**Note:** According to my calculation that i run in wolfram alpha from $n=1$ to $100$ I have got this result as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of[+phi%282%5En-1%29+mod+%28tau%282%5En-1%29%29],n%3D1+to+100) such that it's work which letting me to ask the following question .

**My question here is:** Are the receprocal of each terms of the titled series integers or by other way :Is ${\tau(2^n-1)}$ always  divides $\phi(2^n-1)$  for every integer $n\geq 1$ ? .

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: Do you think this is true? Why? Have you accumulated any evidence? Please tell us what work you have done to investigate this problem. Cheers!

Comment: yes  i think it it is true  i have tried many examples which no counter example

Comment: What is "many examples"? It would be great for you to share the results of your calculations.

Comment: I meant i have tried it it's work with many integer n >=1 , using just wolfram alpha , this let me to conjucture that and i ask here mayeb to accross advanced theory in E.N.T for proving or disproving it !!! I'm interesting for divisiblity among sum of power divisor function and euler totiont function i hop to be good exercice for me to know more about number theory

Comment: What have you tried to do to prove this? Sharing that information would help people know what number theory you understand and thus make better responses.

Comment: @MatthewConroy,i have shared my few computation pleas check it  , and i'm sorry because i don't have enough information for proving or disproof it

Comment: I recommend you consider the prime factorizations of $\tau(2^n-1)$ and $\phi(2^n-1)$ to see if you can make some observations about why one might divide the other.

Comment: oops sry $\phi(87211)$ is divisible by $5$, so even if $2^{54}-1$ has a factor $3^4$, it isn't a counter-example. See [there the factorization of $2^n -1$](http://mersennewiki.org/index.php/2_Minus_Tables) for $n < 1200$

Comment: Ok no problem , i know that you think that , but according to many examples i run it's always work i w'd if there is any point of starting to build a proof abt that

Comment: Now asked (and answered) at MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/254323/any-counter-example-for-this-phi2n-1-bmod-tau2n-1-0-for-every-inte – it seems $n=253$ is the first counterexample.